# Insert 'even numbered' rows into an existing table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| fooID          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| fooDetails     | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| fooListingID   | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| fooStatus      | tinyint(4)   | YES  |     | 0       |                | 
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would like to merge data from a similar table with this table but I would like the data to be alternating so that existing data in this table will all be odd "fooID" and the new inserts will all be the even "fooID".

Ideas?

Comment: This smells the the beginning of a very bad idea. Why would you want to do this? 

You'd be much better off adding another column if you want to store an attribute of that row rather than relying on an obscure trick like storing information in the odd/even status of the identity column.

If you could give some background on why you would want to do this, someone might be able to offer a better solution to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've interpreted your problem as you make to make all the existing fooIDs odd, and then merge into that table some new, even fooIDs.

You can accomplish this fairly easily:

```
#first make all the existing ids odd
UPDATE oldtable SET fooID=fooID*2-1;

#now insert rows from the other table, making sure the ids are even    
INSERT INTO oldtable (fooID,fooDetails,fooListingID,fooStatus)
    SELECT fooID*2,fooDetails,fooListingID,fooStatus FROM newtable;
```

Comment: Worked as intended.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the result of a select statement. Use [modulo](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) for alternating ids:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable
SELECT column1, column2
FROM OldTable
WHERE NOT id % 2
```

Comment: For even rows only, you would want "WHERE id % 2"

Comment: This techique loses every other row of OldTable, I'm not sure that's what the OP wanted?